# Is there a way to restart automatically the HHVM service if I get a '502 Bad Gateway Error'?

Tags: nginx, scripting, cron, php

I've [reported the error on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912682/hhvm-stops-working-111-connection-refused-message-on-nginx-with-pagespeed) - from time to time my Nginx/PageSpeed+HHVM+MariaDB+WordPress blog stops working. There is some problem with the HHVM service that I don't locate, and I'm thinking on two workarounds:

1. Restart the service hourly (for example) with a cron job. This would minimize the problem to 1 hour max.
2. Configure some kind of If This Then That action. I don't know if this is possible. I receive email alerts from Pingdom when a 520 Bad Gateway Error occurs, so I was wondering if I could run a little script (sudo service hhvm restart) to get everything working only when that alert comes.

Mmmm :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) which is designed to do what you describe in option 2

Comment: Seems the perfect fit, thanks! I'll take a good look at it :)

Answer (score 2):

You could write a shell script to check if hhvm is running if not then start it,  write a cron to execute every minute ( This script needs to be executed as root )

**Update** Monit is a preferred solution, following solution is if you don't want to install monit.

```
PID=/var/run/hhvm/pid
if [ ! -f $PID ]; then
        date
        echo "Starting HHVM..."
        service hhvm start
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

ps-watcher is a tool that watches which processes are running and executes an action on defined circumstances - I have been using this to keep HHVM running